# Symbian-Carbide: Can't update 2.3.0 to 2.5.0

Tags: symbian, carbide

Just installed the SDK and ADK.
while updating, it gives the following error:
"unexpected end of zlib input stream" a dozen times.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I managed to find a link to download the latest release of Carbide directly:
http://tools.ext.nokia.com/download/dev_build.php